# How to read JSON body in HttpActionExecutedContext in case of exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpcontext

We are using Web API 2 and to handle exception we have create a custom attribute by inheriting the ExceptionFilterAttribute. Now we want to save the logs of JSON request to database in case of exception .

I tried to read using context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result but its returning empty string.

Please help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset request stream position and reread it:

```
class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var stream = await context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var requestString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and providing the solution but when I am using OnException method then why I am not able to read the request body. Please suggest.

Comment: Because the request stream is already parsed and read by the framework. You can use the same trick as I did with seeking stream to beginning.